# Convergence series problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to show that $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n(\ln n)(\ln \ln n)^p}$$ converges if and only if $p>1$ ?

By integral test, 
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n(\ln n)(\ln \ln n)^p}$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x(\ln x)(\ln \ln x)^P}$$

$$\int_{3}^{\infty }\frac{1}{x(\ln x)(\ln \ln x)^p}$$

I stucked at here.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406040/for-which-alpha-this-sum-converges-sum-n-3-infty-frac1n-cdot-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_3^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x(\log x)(\log \log x)^p}$$Let $u=\log \log x$.  Then, $du=\frac{dx}{x \log x}$.
$$\int_3^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x(\log x)(\log \log x)^p}=\int_{\log \log 3}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^p}$$This indefinite integral equals $\frac{u^{1-p}}{1-p}$ for $p \ne 1$ and equals $\log u$ for $p=1$.  If $p>1$, then $$\lim_{u\to \infty} \frac{u^{1-p}}{1-p}=0$$  Thus, the integral converges as an improper Riemann integral.  And by the integral test for series convergence, the series of interest converges also!

Comment: How to proceed from where I stuck? thanks. @Dr. MV

Comment: Yes, the answer provides this. Simply use the substitution that is embedded in the answer.  After substitution, the integrand is an elementary one.

Comment: Mathxx Thanks for the "best answer" designation!

Comment: welcome :) I also understand what you've explained . Thanks !

Comment: @Mathxx My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test):
For a non-negative, non-decreasing sequence $a_n$ of reals, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}<\infty$$

Applied to your situation we get that your series converges if and only if

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^p}$$

converges, which by applying the Cauchy condensation test *again* converges if and only if

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$$

converges. Now for this one you should now that it converges iff $p>1$.

Note that, for the sake of clarity, I ignored constants coming from $\ln 2$ that pop up.

Comment: Do you know where's a good resource to learn this test ? @Your Ad Here

Comment: This answer here and the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the *integral test*.

Comment: Can you show me how to use integral test or give me a good resource to learn this test? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence is a good place to start.

Comment: Can you show me? Thanks. I edited the problem.